# What's the simple way to compute the diagonal length of a 3D mesh bounding box?

Tags: 3d, geometry, mesh

I would like to compute the diagonal length of the bounding box of a 3D mesh. Using C++, I iterate of the vertices and search for the (min,max) of X coordinates, (min,max) of Y coordinates and (min,max) of Z coordinates. However I don't know how can I exploit these obtained min/max for the computation of the diagonal length of the bounding box. 
Any help please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions

Comment: @MBo, you mean that I should consider the maximum Euclidean distance between all 3D points?

Comment: @ananass Distance between two opposite corners is space diagonal length

Comment: @MBo, Yes the distance ebtween two opposite corners is the diagonal length, however I don't understand how can I define the 8 corners of a target 3D mesh

Comment: @spektre, can you provide a tutorial which explains the OBB for 3D models?

Comment: @ananass min/max coordinates define OBB. OBB vertices might not coincide with mesh vertices

Comment: @MBo, Ok I got it. Simply consider 2 novel points (max_x, max_y_max_z) and (min_x, min_y, min_z) and compute the distance between these two points in order to get the length of the diagonal of BB. Thank you

Comment: @Spektre, yes, thank you, I would like to see your optimized code ;)

Comment: @ananass  I added the 3D OBB port as Answer. Btw. you want just the length of 2 most distant points or the OBB itself? as the length of 2 most distant points in mesh is simple O(n^2) brute force search (and has no direct relation to OBB AABB) and there are even faster methods using spatial ordering of points ...

Comment: @Spektre, I want the length of the diagonal of OBB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity let us consider a list of `n` 3D points (point cloud) as input (instead of mesh) which is enough for polygonal meshes.

The "diagonal" of the mesh is just line between 2 most distant points in the mesh. That is easily computable with trivial `O(n^2)` brute force search (2 nested for loops remembering most distant points). There are also faster methods that exploit ordering of points. Here the brute force example:

```cpp
line pointcloud::diagonal()
    {
    int i,j;
    line l,ll;
    l=line(vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0),vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0)); // empty line
    for (i=0;i<pnt.num-1;i++)                    // O(n^2) search through all point pairs
     for (j=i+1;j<pnt.num-1;j++)
        {
        ll=line(pnt.dat[i],pnt.dat[j]);          // prepare line
        if (l.l<ll.l) l=ll;                      // compare sizes and remember the longer one
        }
    return l;
    }
```

For more info about `line` and `pointcloud` classes implementation read the links below and source code for the OBB.

However from the comments I got the feeling you need **3D OBB** (oriented bounding box) instead of just diagonal. What you have right now is just **AABB** (axis aligned bounding box) which will not give you the mesh diagonal (unless its in lucky orientation that matches **AABB** diagonal).

**Beware both AABB and OBB diagonal is not the same as mesh diagonal !!!**

There are many methods to compute **OBB** from brute force (~`O(n^6)`) to faster using eigen vectors, convex hull etc...

I managed to port my [2D OBB approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997918/2521214) into 3D.

The idea is the same. Store max distances in "all" (`m`) possible directions/angles (covering full sphere instead of circle in 2D) reducing data from `n` to `m`. And then just search the computed data for minimal bounding volume (instead of area in 2D).

I used my [Cone to box collision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214) for testing and as a start point.

The algo:

1. **compute pivot point `p0`**

   it must be inside point of the OBB. usually center of AABB or avg point is enough for this.
2. **compute distances in each possible direction**

   there is infinite number of possible  directions so we need to limit this to `m`. the bigger the `m` the slower computation but more accurate. In order to store and obtain these values fast I used `cube_map`.

   Its a 2D texture covering the surface of unit cube (6 x square sides) and its addressed by direction vector instead of texture coordinates.

   I implemented 2 functions that convert between `index` in texture data (stored as 1D array) and `direction` vector. For more info see `cube_map` in  the example...

   The distance `d` of point `p` from `p0` in some direction `dir` is computed like this:

   ```
   d = dot( p-p0 , dir )
   ```

   so generate `m` possible directions, and for each compute distance for all points in your source list of point and remember the biggest one which is then stored to `cube_map` for latter. This is `O(`m*n`)`

   Here example of stored distances for one frame (content of cube_map):

   [image: distances in directions]
3. **find minimal bounding volume**

   Simply generate all `m` rotations of some coordinate system (covering half sphere). You do not need to cover full sphere because the other half is just negation...

   Now for each compute volume by getting the distances along its 3 axises in both directions and computing the volume of formed box and remember the smallest one (axises, distances and volume). There is possibility of having unitialized data in the `cube_map` which results in `volume = 0` (if cube_map was cleared to zero at start) due rounding and nonlinearity problems so ignore such just volumes.

   After this you should have your **OBB** aproximation. Here preview of **OBB** for few rotated positions:

   [image: OBB preview]

   Its a bit jumpy because for such symmetric shape there are infinite number of valid **OBB**s and in different rotations different one can be found first in search.
4. **improve accuracy**

   Simply search few rotations nearby found **OBB** aproximation and remember the smallest one. This can be done recursively. However I am too lazy to implement this as current state of OBB result is enough for me.

**Here C++/GL source (the rest can be found in the link above):**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class pointcloud
    {
public:
    // cfg
    List<vec3> pnt;

    pointcloud()    {}
    pointcloud(pointcloud& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~pointcloud()   {}
    pointcloud* operator = (const pointcloud *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //pointcloud* operator = (const pointcloud &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    void reset(){ pnt.num=0; }
    void add(vec3 p){ pnt.add(p); }
    void add(point p){ pnt.add(p.p0); }
    void compute(){};
    void draw()
        {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        for (int i=0;i<pnt.num;i++) glVertex3fv(pnt.dat[i].dat);
        glEnd();
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<class T,int N> class cube_map
    {
public:
    int n,nn,sz;
    float fn2;
    T map[6*N*N];

    cube_map()  { n=N; nn=N*N; sz=6*nn; fn2=0.5*float(n); }
    cube_map(cube_map& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~cube_map() {}
    cube_map* operator = (const cube_map *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //cube_map* operator = (const cube_map &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    vec3 ix2dir(int ix)
        {
        float x,y;
        vec3 dir=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        if ((ix<0)||(ix>=sz)) return dir;
        x=ix%n; ix/=n; x/=fn2; x--;
        y=ix%n; ix/=n; y/=fn2; y--;
        if (ix==0){ dir.y=x; dir.z=y; dir.x=-1.0; }
        if (ix==1){ dir.y=x; dir.z=y; dir.x=+1.0; }
        if (ix==2){ dir.x=x; dir.z=y; dir.y=-1.0; }
        if (ix==3){ dir.x=x; dir.z=y; dir.y=+1.0; }
        if (ix==4){ dir.x=x; dir.y=y; dir.z=-1.0; }
        if (ix==5){ dir.x=x; dir.y=y; dir.z=+1.0; }
        return normalize(dir);
        }
    int dir2ix(vec3 dir)
        {
        int ix=0,x=0,y=0;
        float a=0.0,b;
        b=fabs(dir.x); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.x<0) ix=0; else ix=1; }
        b=fabs(dir.y); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.y<0) ix=2; else ix=3; }
        b=fabs(dir.z); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.z<0) ix=4; else ix=5; }
        dir/=a;
        dir+=vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        dir*=fn2;
        if (ix==0){ x=dir.y; y=dir.z; }
        if (ix==1){ x=dir.y; y=dir.z; }
        if (ix==2){ x=dir.x; y=dir.z; }
        if (ix==3){ x=dir.x; y=dir.z; }
        if (ix==4){ x=dir.x; y=dir.y; }
        if (ix==5){ x=dir.x; y=dir.y; }
        ix=(ix*nn)+(y*n)+(x);
        if ((ix<0)||(ix>=sz)) ix=0;
        return ix;
        }
    void set(vec3 dir,T &a){        map[dir2ix(dir)]=a; }
    T    get(vec3 dir     ){ return map[dir2ix(dir)];   }
    void clear(T &a){ for (int i=0;i<sz;i++) map[i]=a; }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class OBB   // Oriented Bounding Box
    {
public:
    // computed
    vec3 p0;        // center
    vec3 u,v,w;     // basis half vectors (p0 origin)

    OBB()   {}
    OBB(OBB& a) { *this=a; }
    ~OBB()  {}
    OBB* operator = (const OBB *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //OBB* operator = (const OBB &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    void compute(pointcloud &pcl)
        {
        const int N=24;
        int i,j,k,na=6*N,nb=2*N;
        cube_map<float,N> map;
        mat4 m,ma;
        vec3 o,p,q,pp0;
        int a,b;
        float da,db,d,dd,e,ee,V,VV;
        p0=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        u=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        v=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        w=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        if (pcl.pnt.num<=0) return;
        // init constants and stuff
        da=2.0*M_PI/float(na  );
        db=    M_PI/float(nb-1);
        // compute avg point
        for (j=0;j<pcl.pnt.num;j++) p0+=pcl.pnt.dat[j];
        p0/=pcl.pnt.num;
        // [compute perpendicular distances]
        // fill whole surface of cubemap
        for (map.clear(0.0),i=0;i<map.sz;i++)
            {
            // cube map index to 3D direction
            p=map.ix2dir(i);
            // compute max distance from p0 in direction p
            d=dot(pcl.pnt.dat[0]-p0,p);
            for (j=1;j<pcl.pnt.num;j++)
                {
                dd=dot(pcl.pnt.dat[j]-p0,p);
                if (d<dd) d=dd;
                }
            // store it in cube map for latter
            map.map[i]=d;
            }
        // [pick the smallest volume OBB combination]
        V=1e300; pp0=p0;
        // try half of "all" rotations (the other one is just negation)
        ma=mat4 // unit matrix -> unrotated coordinate system
            (
            1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
            0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,
            0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,
            0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
            );
        for (                             a=0;a<na;a+=2,ma=lrotz(ma,da))
         for (m=lroty(ma,float(-0.5*M_PI)),b=0;b<nb;b++,m=lroty(m,db))
            {
            // get OBB per orientation of m
            p.x=map.get(-m[0].xyz);
            q.x=map.get(+m[0].xyz);
            p.y=map.get(-m[1].xyz);
            q.y=map.get(+m[1].xyz);
            p.z=map.get(-m[2].xyz);
            q.z=map.get(+m[2].xyz);
            o=p+q;
            VV=fabs(o.x*o.y*o.z);
            if ((V>VV)&&(VV>1e-6))
                {
                V=VV;
                u=m[0].xyz;
                v=m[1].xyz;
                w=m[2].xyz;
                o*=0.5;
                pp0=p0+(u*(o.x-p.x))+(v*(o.y-p.y))+(w*(o.z-p.z));
                u*=o.x;
                v*=o.y;
                w*=o.z;
                }
            }
        p0=pp0;
        }
    void draw()
        {
        const vec3 p[8]=
            {
            p0-u-v-w,
            p0+u-v-w,
            p0+u+v-w,
            p0-u+v-w,
            p0-u-v+w,
            p0+u-v+w,
            p0+u+v+w,
            p0-u+v+w,
            };
        const int ix[24]=
            {
            0,1,1,2,2,3,3,0,
            4,5,5,6,6,7,7,4,
            0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7,
            };
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        for (int i=0;i<24;i++) glVertex3fv(p[ix[i]].dat);
        glEnd();
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hope I did not forget to copy something... I wanted to keep the code as simple as I could so its not very optimized and there is a lot of room for improvement. The math used is **GLSL** based so you can use **GLM**. I used my own libs for that the `vec` can be found in the links above if needed (but need to be generated as its ~220KByte of code) but is matches GLSL and GLM exactly so you cn use that. The `mat4` however use some functions that are not present in GLM in such format so just in case:

```cpp
template <class T> class _mat4
    {
public:
    _vec4<T> col[4];    // columns!!!
    _mat4(T a00,T a01,T a02,T a03,T a04,T a05,T a06,T a07,T a08,T a09,T a10,T a11,T a12,T a13,T a14,T a15)
        {
        col[0]=vec4(a00,a01,a02,a03);   // x axis
        col[1]=vec4(a04,a05,a06,a07);   // y axis
        col[2]=vec4(a08,a09,a10,a11);   // z axis
        col[3]=vec4(a12,a13,a14,a15);   // origin
        }
    _mat4()
        {
        col[0]=vec4(1,0,0,0);
        col[1]=vec4(0,1,0,0);
        col[2]=vec4(0,0,1,0);
        col[3]=vec4(0,0,0,1);
        }
    _mat4(const _mat4& a) { *this=a; }
    ~_mat4() {}
    // operators (matrix math)
    _mat4* operator = (const _mat4 &a) { for (int i=0;i<4;i++) col[i]=a.col[i]; return this; }  // =a[][]
    _vec4<T>& operator [](const int i){ return col[i]; }                                        // a[i]
    _mat4<T> operator * (_mat4<T>&m)                                                            // =a[][]*m[][]
        {
        _mat4<T> q;
        int i,j,k;
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
         for (j=0;j<4;j++)
          for (q.col[i][j]=0,k=0;k<4;k++)
           q.col[i][j]+=col[k][j]*m.col[i][k];
        return q;
        }
    _mat4<T> operator * (_vec4<T>&v)                                                            // =a[][]*v[]
        {
        _vec4<T> q;
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
         for (q.dat[i]=0,j=0;j<4;j++)
           q.dat[i]+=col[i][j]*v.dar[j];
        return q;
        }
    _mat4<T> operator * (T &c)                                                                  // =a[][]*c
        {
        _mat4<T> q;
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
         for (j=0;j<4;j++)
          q.dat[i]=col[i][j]*c;
        return q;
        }
    _mat4<T> operator / (T &c)                                                                  // =a[][]/c
        {
        _mat4<T> q;
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
         for (j=0;j<4;j++)
          q.dat[i]=divide(col[i][j],c);
        return q;
        }
    _mat4<T> operator *=(_mat4<T>&m){ this[0]=this[0]*m; return *this; };
    _mat4<T> operator *=(_vec4<T>&v){ this[0]=this[0]*v; return *this; };
    _mat4<T> operator *=(const T &c){ this[0]=this[0]*c; return *this; };
    _mat4<T> operator /=(const T &c){ this[0]=this[0]/c; return *this; };
    // members
    void get(T *a)
        {
        int i,j,k;
        for (k=0,i=0;i<4;i++)
         for (j=0;j<4;j++,k++)
          a[k]=col[i].dat[j];
        }
    void set(T *a)
        {
        int i,j,k;
        for (k=0,i=0;i<4;i++)
         for (j=0;j<4;j++,k++)
          col[i].dat[j]=a[k];
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> _mat4<T> transpose(const _mat4<T> &m)
    {
    _mat4<T> q;
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
     for (j=0;j<4;j++)
      q.col[i][j]=m.col[j][i];
    return q;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> _mat4<T> inverse(_mat4<T> &m)
    {
    T p[3];
    _mat4<T> q;
    T x,y,z;
    int i,j;
    // transpose rotation
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) for (j=0;j<3;j++) q.col[i][j]=m.col[j][i];
    // copy projection
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) q.col[i][3]=m.col[i][3];
    // convert origin: new_pos = - new_rotation_matrix * old_pos
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) for (p[i]=0,j=0;j<3;j++) p[i]+=q.col[j][i]*m.col[3][j];
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) q.col[3][i]=-p[i];
    return q;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> _mat4<T> lrotx(_mat4<T> &m,T ang)
    {
    T c=cos(ang),s=sin(ang);
    _mat4<T> r=mat4(
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, c, s, 0,
         0,-s, c, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1);
    r=m*r; return r;
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> _mat4<T> lroty(_mat4<T> &m,T ang)
    {
    T c=cos(ang),s=sin(ang);
    _mat4<T> r=mat4(
         c, 0,-s, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 0,
         s, 0, c, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1);
    r=m*r; return r;
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> _mat4<T> lrotz(_mat4<T> &m,T ang)
    {
    T c=cos(ang),s=sin(ang);
    _mat4<T> r=mat4(
         c, s, 0, 0,
        -s, c, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1);
    r=m*r; return r;
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> _mat4<T> rotate(_mat4<T> &m,T ang,_vec3<T> p0,_vec3<T> dp)
    {
    int i;
    T c=cos(ang),s=sin(ang);
    _vec3<T> x,y,z;
    _mat4<T> a,_a,r=mat4(
         1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, c, s, 0,
         0,-s, c, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1);
    // basis vectors
    x=normalize(dp);    // axis of rotation
    y=_vec3<T>(1,0,0);  // any vector non parallel to x
    if (fabs(dot(x,y))>0.75) y=_vec3<T>(0,1,0);
    z=cross(x,y);       // z is perpendicular to x,y
    y=cross(z,x);       // y is perpendicular to x,z
    y=normalize(y);
    z=normalize(z);
    // feed the matrix
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        a[0][i]= x[i];
        a[1][i]= y[i];
        a[2][i]= z[i];
        a[3][i]=p0[i];
        a[i][3]=0;
        } a[3][3]=1;
    _a=inverse(a);
    r=m*a*r*_a;
    return r;
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> _mat4<T> grotx(_mat4<T> &m,T ang){ return inverse(lrotx(inverse(m),ang)); };
template <class T> _mat4<T> groty(_mat4<T> &m,T ang){ return inverse(lroty(inverse(m),ang)); };
template <class T> _mat4<T> grotz(_mat4<T> &m,T ang){ return inverse(lrotz(inverse(m),ang)); };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef _mat4<float >  mat4;
typedef _mat4<double> dmat4;
typedef _mat4<bool  > bmat4;
typedef _mat4<int   > imat4;
typedef _mat4<DWORD > umat4;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
mat4 GLSL_math_test4x4;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In order to understand it or write your own I recommend to see:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

And lastly I also used mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

**Now the result in OBB**

its just box described by its center `p0` and half vectors `u,v,w`. So to obtain **OBB** of pointcloud `PCL` just compute:

```cpp
OBB obb;
pointcloud PCL;
PCL.reset();
PCL.add(...); // here feed points into PCL
obb.compute(PCL);
```

and that is all.

Comment: btw I managed to create the recursive accuracy boost for OBB (both 2D and 3D) by using zoomed square_map and cube_map for the recursions (with very small change of the current code both square/cube map and OBB) where each face of square/cube will no longer cover `90deg` but `90deg/zoom`  instead so no more memory is needed to allocate and the same variables can be used in each iteration of the accuracy increase and also only directions near last found one are used instead of full coverage of entire space. However new code is too long to post as it contains a lot of stuff for both 2D and 3D

Comment: Also I normalized the code so 2D is analogy to 3D and all the stuff can be easily ported to 4D or higher dimensions as the algorithms are the same. The 2D/3D geometry stuff is ~64KByte and vector/matrix math ~243KByte.