# How to standardize scale for meshes

Tags: geometry, mesh, wavefront

I am comparing 3 different obj files and all 3 have different ranges of vertices. How can I standardize them to all fit on the same coordinate system? For example, a unit in +x direction is +1 for some obj but +0.1 for other obj. Would this be solved in the export side of things?

Obj file 1:

```
...
v -58.3252 18.5699 -5.90483
v -68.6891 17.7611 -5.90483
v -75.0724 15.5657 -5.90483
v -77.2501 11.2904 -5.90483
v -74.8073 5.4943 -1.10804
v -71.2985 -1.50103 -1.10804
v -65.1248 -8.49634 -1.10804
v -56.0198 -14.2925 -1.10804
v -76.0183 4.93477 3.68876
v -72.159 -2.35462 3.68876
v -65.4267 -9.55033 3.68876
v -55.5757 -15.6249 3.68876
v -78.6824 3.70383 5.28769
v -74.0522 -4.23253 5.28769
...
```

Obj file 2:

```
...
v 8.8628 -13.0972 -5.24432
v 7.6291 -13.7026 -6.29806
v 8.13551 -16.3413 -2.70127
v 9.13848 -14.3695 -4.15261
v 4.40254 -17.2081 -4.49678
v 4.26564 -17.9077 -2.68561
v 5.86252 -17.6355 -2.49267
v 6.48562 -16.5955 -4.15049
v 6.93278 -14.8793 -5.85708
v 5.30878 -14.5859 -7.1558
v 4.33214 -15.6151 -6.57886
v 7.49304 -16.145 -3.85419
...
```

Obj file 3:

```
...
v  0.0952 0.8021 0.3419
v  0.0957 0.7628 0.3562
v  0.0947 0.8401 0.3281
v  0.0959 0.7459 0.3623
v  0.0936 0.8531 0.2961
v  0.0945 0.8570 0.3219
v  0.2531 0.8454 0.2899
v  0.2539 0.8285 0.2961
v  0.2548 0.8285 0.2961
...
```

Comment: compute AABB or [OBB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62284464/2521214) and scale down by sizes to obtain "unit size" object you can also translate the center of BBox  to the same coordinate like `(0,0,0)` and or orient the largest side of BBox to common direction like `X+` ...

Comment: Without more context, your question does not make sense. What is the rationale of comparing objects of different size or measurement unit ? If they are the same object, you need to *register* them. If not, how do they relate ?